# Insert records in RalationAShips tables when adding a new record in Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**I have two linked tables:**

The first is Table (students)
Int ID_Student
String Name_Student
Int ID_Class

The second is Table ( Std_Class)
Int ID_Class
String Name_Class

Associated with column (ID_Class)

**the problem :**

When adding a new student (whether in the database by :Context.SaveChanges;
, or adding to memory only), I also enter the list of chapters in the (Std_Class) column, in order to use this list in the event that I do not want to save the row in the Database.

*When saved to the database it is actually saved to the student table, but it also adds a new class.*

Code :

```
        studentEntities cn = new StudentEntities();
        students stu= new students();
        std_Class cls = cn.Room_Rate.FirstOrDefault();
        stu.Name_Student= "Inter Name";
        Stu.Std_Class = cls ;
        cn.students.Add(stu);
        cn.SaveChanges();
```

**I used the property(AsNoTracking) But without interest**

When adding a new student, a new class is also added
I don't know why, because I assigned the class schedule in the addition process?
Although I need the backup and necessary, because the data is either for saving or for display, when displaying data there is no problem, only when saving does the addition and it is my problem
This is an example illustrating the problem

Comment: Consider adhering to C# naming conventions to make your code more clear.  Class names should begin with an uppercase letter, property names should begin with an uppercase letter, and variable names should begin with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Very sorry, I will try to amend the question

Comment: try `std_Class cls = cn.Room_Rate.AsTracking().FirstOrDefault();`